# ppp connect random disconnect

Tags: networking, server, network-manager, ppp

when i connect the ppp, the network connection is ok.

but after n minuter, the connection will disconect random.

> 14:54:25 pptp[435]: anon warn[open_inetsock:pptp_callmgr.c:329]: connect: Connection timed out
>
> 14:54:25 pptp[435]: anon fatal[callmgr_main:pptp_callmgr.c:127]: Could not open control connection to 36.224.111.201
>
> 14:54:25 pptp[431]: anon fatal[open_callmgr:pptp.c:487]: Call manager exited with error 256
>
> 14:54:52 pptp[481]: anon warn[open_inetsock:pptp_callmgr.c:329]: connect: Connection timed out
>
> 14:54:52 pptp[481]: anon fatal[callmgr_main:pptp_callmgr.c:127]: Could not open control connection to 36.224.111.201
>
> 14:54:52 pptp[477]: anon fatal[open_callmgr:pptp.c:487]: Call manager exited with error 256
>
> 14:55:15 pptp[538]: anon log[logecho:pptp_ctrl.c:677]: Echo Reply received.
>
> 14:56:15 pptp[538]: anon log[logecho:pptp_ctrl.c:677]: Echo Reply received.
>
> 14:57:15 pptp[538]: anon log[logecho:pptp_ctrl.c:677]: Echo Reply received.
>
> 14:58:16 pptp[538]: anon log[logecho:pptp_ctrl.c:677]: Echo Reply received.
>
> 14:59:16 pptp[538]: anon log[logecho:pptp_ctrl.c:677]: Echo Reply received.
>
> 15:00:16 pptp[538]: anon log[logecho:pptp_ctrl.c:677]: Echo Reply received.
>
> 15:01:16 pptp[538]: anon log[logecho:pptp_ctrl.c:677]: Echo Reply received.
>
> 15:02:17 pptp[538]: anon log[logecho:pptp_ctrl.c:677]: Echo Reply received.
>
> 15:03:17 pptp[538]: anon log[logecho:pptp_ctrl.c:677]: Echo Reply received.
>
> 15:03:17 pptp[538]: anon log[logecho:pptp_ctrl.c:679]: no more Echo Reply/Request packets will be reported.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? It's not that clear, your question.

Answer (score 0):

i got it.

1: /etc/ppp/options

```
lcp-echo-failure 10 # (from /etc/ppp/options)
lcp-echo-interval 10    # (from /etc/ppp/options)
lock
crtscts
nodeflate
persist
asyncmap 0
noauth
hide-password
noipx
```

2. nohup make background python job.

> nohup python3 /root/linux/PPTP_Linux2/main.py &
>
> ps ax | grep py